# rescraping content of already shared url using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anyone have idea about updating the content of shared link using facebook graph api?
I have gone through some links in which it is mentioned that we can use "scrape=true" parameter along with the shared link, but in facebook doc it is mentioned that "Once the metadata has been updated using the "scrape=true" parameter, it will be used for all new shares of your link. If you've already shared the link, it will continue to display the old data." 
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to update this data in posts people already made in the past?

That is not possible via API - for the obvious reason, that you would not want me to change that link that you shared three days ago on your profile, and that said something about cute kittens at the time, to say “Buy cheap V1agr4 here!” now.

The person/page that shared your link can do this manually, if they want to - the context menu of a post offers an option “refresh share attachment”.